# branch permission conf with gitolite

Tags: git, github, gitolite

I am setting up Git Repos for my firm but I would like to give access to release leads and developers to diff things..  I starting to use GitoLite but dont know if this can be done of if someone has something better.

Here is the issues:

**users that are in @releases:** can create branchs, update master, sql and create tags.

**users that are in @developers:** can create branches under fix/issueXXXX, push and pull to them but cant update master or sqa... can pull from them but never update them

Here is my gitolite.conf

```
@releasers = xsmith xrice
@developers = dev1 dev2 dev3

repo project
    RW+      = xsmith
    RW+ master   = @releasers     # allow @releasers access to release branch
    - master     = @developers    # deny @developers access to release branch
    RW+ develop  = @developers    # allow @developers access to development branch
    RW+ develop  = @releasers     # allow @developers access to development branch
    RW refs/tags = @releasers
    RW refs/heads = @releasers
```

but with the above file the developers cant create new branchs etc...  can someone please help me out with this.. also I want it so the developers can pull from master,sqa and develop but cant update them and cant create new branchs under fix/

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in a similar situation a few years ago.

If you want someone to have only read access on a branch, modify the file giving "R" permissions (from Read) intead of "-".

For your case i recommend you to use forks, it was easier for me to adminstrate a medium sized developers group whit a high rotation. Forks will allow you to implement what you need. Giving you on the go some advantages.

In the forked repository the @developers have write access and can push changes. They may contribute back to the original repository using pull requests (which are accepted by the @releasers).

Here are some advantages:

1) You are no longer tied to specific branch names, such as master or development, giving you more flexibility.

2) For implement different roles, you just have to give privileges RW to each fork/user

3) It is easy to see on a spot what is the code that is passing trough the fork and main repo, and there is a responsable for each accepted pull request, which you may find useful.

Here is the fork doc on github: https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo.
Here is a question that may result interesting: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200663/why-do-people-fork-repositories-on-github

I hope it helps.